# get single records using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In Foreach loop of php i get on click event only 'product_title' and 'email'. code is as bellow.

```
foreach($abs_records as $abs)
{
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="case[]" class="case" ></td>
        <td><?php echo $abs['product_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $abs['product_title']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $abs['user_email']; ?></td>
        <td class="send_mail_btn"><a href="javascript:void(0)" >Send</a></td>
    </tr><?php
} ?>
```

Using Jquery click on 'Send' i will get the result of **Single Time value** of 'Product_title' and  'user_email'

Can you suggest me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to the td element like so:

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="case[]" class="case" ></td>
    <td><?php echo $abs['product_id']; ?></td>
    <td class="title"><?php echo $abs['product_title']; ?></td>
    <td class="email"><?php echo $abs['user_email']; ?></td>
    <td class="send_mail_btn"><a href="javascript:void(0)" >Send</a></td>
</tr>
```

Than you can find the related values in jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.send_mail_btn', function() {
  var title = $(this).siblings('.title').html();
  var email = $(this).siblings('.email').html();
  console.log("Title: " + title);
  console.log("Email: " + email);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add class to email and title td and also add class to send anchor tag + add click event in jquery to get value

```
  foreach($abs_records as $abs)
    {
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="case[]" class="case" ></td>
            <td><?php echo $abs['product_id']; ?></td>
            <td class="title"><?php echo $abs['product_title']; ?></td>
            <td class="email"><?php echo $abs['user_email']; ?></td>
            <td class="send_mail_btn"><a class="send-link" href="javascript:void(0)" >Send</a></td>
        </tr><?php
    } ?>   


    Jquery:

    $(".send-link").click(function() {
    var title = $(this).parent("tr").find(".title").text();
    var email = $(this).parent("tr").find(".email").text();
    alert(title+ " -- "+email)
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for response me. but i think its not working can you help me. here is [link](https://jsfiddle.net/ravi142/bfzd6e8o/)